# Issue in getting data from a tcp port using netty4 component

Tags: java, tcp, apache-camel, netty

I am using Camel Netty4 component to listen data on a TCP port. Below is my code:

```
public class TcpListener {


    public static void main(String hh[]) throws Exception{

        MyMessageDecoder byteDecoder = new MyMessageDecoder();
        SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
        reg.put("decoder", byteDecoder);
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {

                from("netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:5150?decoder=#decoder")
                .to("file://C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop?fileName=tcpOutput.txt");
            }
        });

        context.start();
    }

}

class MyMessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    static FileWriter writer;
    static {
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/tcpOutputNew1.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext context, ByteBuf buffer, List<Object> out) throws Exception {

        if (buffer.readableBytes() < 1) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        buffer.readBytes(bytes);

        MyMessage myMessage = new MyMessage(bytes);
        System.out.println(bytes[0]);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[0]));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(bytes[0]));
        System.out.println(myMessage);

        out.add(myMessage);
    }
}

class MyMessage {

    protected byte data1;

    public MyMessage(byte[] data) {
        data1 = data[0];
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "MyMessage: { " + this.data1 +" }";
    }
}
```

In my code I am trying to read 1 byte at a time because in each byte I will receive IMEI number of device . For IMEI number

```
351608084153316
```

I should receive data like

```
0x03 0x51 0x60 0x80 0x84 0x15 0x33 0x16
```

But data I am receiving is

```
0x03 0x51 0x60 0xffffff80 0xffffff84 0x15 0x33 0x16.
```

How can I resolve this or how can I ignore these unwanted bytes appended with some parts of the IMEI number.

Comment: Those look like signed bytes sign-extended to 32 bits.  What is creating that data?

Comment: I am receiving this data from a gps device. Example I have quoted is IMEI number of the device. Suppose IMEI number is 123456, I am receiving data like   12 ffffff34 56 in hexadecimal.

Comment: @JimGarrison Can you please help as I am not getting signed bytes for all the bytes received.

Comment: _"Suppose IMEI number is 123456"_ -- Please [edit] your question and include a ***real*** example.  I strongly suspect that with a number like `123456` you would not see this problem, but with one like `129F73` you would, as the middle byte is > 127 and gets sign-extended when converted to `int`.  I suspect the solution is as simple as `value & 0x000000FF` but cannot tell unless you provide a real failing example.

Comment: @JimGarrison As suggested I have written the exact scenario. Is that any helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what is happening.

1. You have an array of bytes, which in Java are considered to be *signed* even though you don't care about a sign bit
2. When you attempt to use them, they are automatically "promoted" to `int`.  Since both `byte` and `int` are signed if the leftmost bit is 1 it is propagated leftwards so that the `int` value is the same as the `byte` numerical value.  From you example

   ```
   0x03 0x51 0x60 0x80 0x84 0x15 0x33 0x16
   ```

   The first byte is `0x03` or bit pattern `0000_0011`. This is a positive value and gets promoted to `0x00000003`.  Same for `0x51` and `0x60`. Things are different for 0x80. Its bit pattern is 1000_0000 and its numeric value is `-128`.  When it is promoted, its sign is left-extended, resulting in the `int` value `0xFFFFFF80`, which still has the numerical value `-128`.
3. In actuality, none of this affects you because the bit patterns in the low-order bytes have not changed.  The solution for you is simply to mask out the unwanted bits whenever you access a byte from the array.  As in

   ```
   Integer.toHexString(0x000000FF & (int) bytes[0])
   ```